# Problem RDP to Azure Virtual Desktop through Azure Firewall

Tags: azure

I'm following the learning document here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/protect-virtual-desktop-deployment-azure-firewall/1-introduction

I can successfully RDP to the VM up until the point where I add the routing table, thus routing traffic through the Azure Firewall.

I've double-checked the network and application rules, and they are set exactly as per the document. I even added a catch-all network rule and an RDP rule to open up the firewall to all traffic, but I still can't RDP.

[image: Network Collection Rules]

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect RDP connection to Azure Virtual Desktop through Azure Firewall Make sure to create the NAT rule in firewall like below:

I have created Application and Network rule as same like below:

[image]

Network rule:

[image]

Now, to connect RDP create Nat rule like below:

[image]

In the `destination address,` add the ***public IP address of the firewall*** in the Firewall -> Public IP section. Additionally, include the private IP address of the virtual machine in the `translated address` field like below:

[image]

[image]

To log in to the virtual machine, use the **`firewall IP address`**.

[image]

Now, the virtual machine is successfully connected to the remote desktop as shown below:

[image]

Additionally, ensure that you have added routes in the route table, and for the next hop address, use the **Firewall private IP address**. In the subnet, associate it with the `hostVNet` virtual network and subnet like below:

[image]